# AWS - s3_website and Jahia/JCR WCMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, jahia

Has anyone used s3_website to 'copy' a static website from Jahia (or similar JCR WCMS)? Would like to use the Jahia export tools to export the site, then use s3_website to upload the site + content to an S3 bucket and then use that S3 bucket to serve the pages/content through AWS Cloudfront

Want to do this via Cloudfront as opposed to using Jahia itself as the WCMS to avoid having to make Jahia fully resilient across multiple regions

Anybody done anything similar ?

Comment: Hi ! Do you have any feedback on this project?